# Externally pass values to an Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, model-view-controller, javascript-objects

I'm thinking of separating our MVC-based website's front-end into few components and I was thinking about using Angular for that purpose (e.g. creating cart application that I can include to my view afterwards).

Problem is that I need to pass few variables into that application and I'm wondering how to do that safely and professionally. I was thinking about something like:

1. I'm going to `ng build --prod --aot`
2. I inject all my scripts to my view
3. I inject variables passed to view to my app

... and "code" representation for my thoughts:

**Controller:**

```
public function viewAction()
{
    $this->view->addCss('angular/app/styles.css'); // adds styles for cart app 
    $this->view->addJS('angular/app/scripts.js');  // adds scripts for cart app
    $this->view->setJSVariable('idCustomer', 555); // sets global var idCustomer
}
```

**View:**

```
<!-- bunch of HTML for view ... -->
<script>
    // CartApp would be an angular app.
    CartApp.use([
        idCustomer
    ]);
</script>
```

So my question is... would it be possible (and would it be a good solution) to get the `CartApp` as an object and then make some function (like `use` in above example) that would set/pass the data? (let's say to some globally provided service/component or anything else). Or is there any other way to do this? Like taking the variables from inside the application from the window object? (as they're going to be bound to the window anyways). Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I was going to suggest using input bindings... I've done that before in AngularJS but was surprised to find that using input bindings on the root component isn't supported yet. You can have fun reading this giant issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858

The best post I saw there was [Rob Wormald's](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858#issuecomment-208001943) which had a couple of suggestions:

> - to the initial question, if you really want to grab data from the
>     root, that's possible via
>     https://plnkr.co/edit/nOQuXE8hMkhakDNCNR9u?p=preview - note that it's not an input (because there's no angular context outside of it to do the input...) - its a simple string attribute
>     which you'd need to parse yourself.
> - ideally though, you'd do as
>     @robtown suggested and actually pass the data in javascript, rather
>     than passing it as a DOM string and retrieving / parsing it yourself
>     (which has never really been a supported case in angular, despite the
>     explicit-warned-against usage of ng-init in angular1 to accomplish
>     this) - see https://plnkr.co/edit/PoSd07IBvYm1EzeA2yJR?p=preview for a
>     simple, testable example of how to do this.

So the 2 good options I saw were:

1. Add normal HTML attributes to the root component:

   ```
   <app-root appData='important stuff'></app-root>
   ```

   and use `ElementRef` to fetch them:

   ```
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root'
   })
   export class AppComponent {
     constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       console.log(el.nativeElement.getAttribute('appData'));
     }
   }
   ```

   Would probably work best if you are just dealing with strings or config flags. If you are passing JSON, you will need to manually parse it.
2. Have the server render the data as JavaScript and import it in your app:

   Have the server render something like this to a script tag or JS file that is loaded before Angular is bootstrapped:

   ```
   window.APP_DATA = { ids: [1, 2, 3] }
   ```

   Tell your NgModule about it using a provider:

   ```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

   import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

   @NgModule({
     providers: [{ provide: 'AppData', useValue: (<any> window).APP_DATA }],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```

   And then use it as a normal Angular service:

   ```
   import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root'
   })
   export class AppComponent {
     constructor(@Inject('AppData') appData) {
       console.log(appData.ids);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Especially the second way looks pretty nice. Thank you so much @Scotty.

Comment: I actually had some time to look at it but I couldn't manage to provide the `AppData` the way you did in the second example. Errors I'm having are... `AppData` (the vlaue of `provide` is not specified (it should probably be provided first) and the second one is that the window has no `APP_DATA` property (as it's not a known property of Window inerface). Can you please add some more code samples for the second example of your answer? Not just for me but maybe for other users with the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: I updated the code. I hadn't actually tested it but had compiled it from examples. Sorry about that. I didn't attempt to get the typings right. It might be good to create an interface for your APP_DATA, import it in the component, and use it when you inject it into the constructor: `constructor(@Inject('AppData') appData: MyAppDataInterface)`. Let me know if my updated code works for you. Main changes were using a string in the `provide: ` field, using `(<any> window)`, and using `@Inject`. There might be cleaner ways to do it, so let me know if you find any improvements :)

Comment: @ScottyWaggoner Fair answer but If stored a some value in controller `ViewData['somvalue']` then how could I send that value to `index.html` which is in `ClientApp` directory.

Comment: Thank you a lot for answer! In the 2021 year any ideas how to pass parameters into component from native JS? For example I have Angular app as map. How to use it in another app with user's configuration?